# CSS Grid - Why is "justify-items" grayed out but works?

Tags: html, css, syntax, frontend, css-grid

After experimenting for quite some time to achieve what I want I finally got it working with `justify-items: center;` in a `.div` with `display: grid;`

However, the reason I never tried this was because if I type `justify-items: center;` it is grayed out like when you enter wrong syntax. Im using atom

Can I ignore this? I always assumed grayed out code means wrong (or 'unknown') Syntax

Sorry if this is a really basic question but I was confused since I just started getting into front-end a week ago and didnt find anything about this

Edit:

Looks like this:

```
.div {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  justify-items: center;
}
```

And in Atom the `justify-items: center;` is grayed out but works

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

It's just the css syntax highlighter plugin that's incomplete (there's even a pull request to add support for that https://github.com/atom/language-css/issues/131).

Don't use the syntax highlight as a reference for what's right and wrong, it's just a plugin to provide visual indicators that someone wrote to assist, not to refer to, use proper references like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items instead when in doubt.